# React Native Change Page after 5 seconds

Tags: react-native

I'm newbie in react native and I don't know how to change page after 5 seconds.

I create an **android.index.js** file that will navigate to **LandingPage.js**. What I want to do is, when the LandingPage being loaded, it will wait for 5 seconds and then redirect / navigate to another page.

**index.android.js**

```js
export default class DefaultProject extends Component {
 render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
          <LandingPage/>
        }
      />
  )
```

**LandingPage.js**

```js
export default class LandingPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Image source={require('./images/event3.jpeg')} 
        style={styles.container} />
        //How to redirect to another page from here after 5 secs?

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use a simple `setTimeout`, as you would in a standard JS setup:

```js
export default class LandingPage extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
         // Start counting when the page is loaded
         this.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(()=>{
              // Add your logic for the transition
         }, 5000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
         clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandle); // This is just necessary in the case that the screen is closed before the timeout fires, otherwise it would cause a memory leak that would trigger the transition regardless, breaking the user experience.
    }

    render() {

    return (
        <Image source={require('./images/event3.jpeg')} 
        style={styles.container} />
        //How to redirect to another page from here after 5 secs?

    );
  }


}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, in the componentDidMount, can I put the navigator logic in there although it got no render?

Comment: @Webster Yes, `componentDidMount` fires after `render` finishes.

Comment: hey dude, i add this line on ComponentDidMount function, <NextPage /> , but it's not working

Comment: No, I did not mean that. You cannot render new components, what you have to do is to tell your navigator that you want to move to another page (`navigator.push(...)`, for example). Check the documentation for that and if you run into problems let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using lodash for this:

```js
export default class Splash extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
        _.delay(() => this.props.navigator.replace({ component: 'login' }), 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

This will only work if you have a `Navigator` set up. Check this article:

[React Native Navigator — Navigating Like A Pro in React Native](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-navigator-navigating-like-a-pro-in-react-native-3cb1b6dc1e30#.lrp0jo423)